# How to call an external variable in a forEach loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, foreach, scope, this

I'm trying to call an external variable in a forEach context. Since I'm using an arrow notation this should make the trick but the variable still comes out as undefined.

This is my code:

```
transformSlots (slots) {
 var array = slots;
 var newArray;
 array.forEach(element => {
   var newElement = {
     day: dateFns.getDate(element.slot),
     month: dateFns.getMonth(element.slot),
     year: dateFns.getYear(element.slot),
     hour: dateFns.getHours(element.slot),
     numInterview: element.num,
     id_users_pending: 0,
     id_users_accepted: 0
   };
   this.newArray.push(newElement);
 });
 return array;
}
```

EDIT:
If I take .this away the result is exactly the same.

Comment: change `this.newArray.push(newElement);` to `newArray.push(newElement);`

Comment: newArray is only declared but `not assigned any value like empty array`. so. doing newArray.push(newElement);  will also be wrong. instarting it should be `var newArray = []` then, `newArray.push(newElement);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `this`. It will make the code look for newarray in the callback and not outside the loop

```js
transformSlots (slots) {
 var array = slots;
 var newArray;
 array.forEach(element => {
   var newElement = {
     day: dateFns.getDate(element.slot),
     month: dateFns.getMonth(element.slot),
     year: dateFns.getYear(element.slot),
     hour: dateFns.getHours(element.slot),
     numInterview: element.num,
     id_users_pending: 0,
     id_users_accepted: 0
   };
   newArray.push(newElement);
 });
 return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `newArray.push(newElement);` instead of `this.newArray.push(newElement);`.

If you print `this` in the `forEach` loop you'll find that the `newArray` isn't bind to `this`.